# SAS Aggregate to show results for the current year only

Tags: sas

I have a table where I compare the results week to week.
[image]

I have aggregations of old dates using these functions.

```
%let date_old=%sysfunc(intnx(year,%sysfunc(Today()),-1,s));
%put &=date_old;
proc format;
   value vintf low-&date_old = 'OLD' other=[yymmd7.];
run;
/*agregujemy wyniki do daty vintf jako old*/
proc summary data=tablea_new nway;
   class policy_vintage;
   format policy_vintage vintf.;
   var AKTYWNE WYGASLE;
   output out=newtabe sum=;
```

And I would like to do exactly the same, only to aggregate the dates to show the yearly range, i.e. 2021-01-2022-01. Or the current year 2021-01-2021-12. Is the following sample okay? What's the best way to do this?

```
%let date_future=%sysfunc(intnx(year,%sysfunc(Today()),+12,s));
%put &=date_future;
proc format;
   value vintfutr +&date_future= 'FUTURE' other=[yymmd7.];
run;
```

Comment: is your `policy_vintage` column numeric?

Comment: yes its numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%let date_old=%sysfunc(intnx(year,%sysfunc(Today()),-1,s));
%let date_future=%sysfunc(intnx(year,%sysfunc(Today()),+1,s));
proc format;
value vintf
  low-&date_old = 'OLD'
  &date_future-high = 'FUTURE'
  other=[yymmd7.]
;
```

run;